# How to make the whole column as numeric while exporting JSON to excel using Java Script

Tags: javascript, json, excel, types, export

I am using xlsx.core.min.js to export json object into excel; I am changing format of each cell by iterating through them. 
There are cells with blank data which were also written into the excel.

The problem is when a column has more blank cells and few cells with numbers, the excel is considering that whole column as Text column which should not be happening, if the column has one number it should b consider that as a number field only.

I referred this for converting data to numbers https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/966
How to resolve this issue, need help!!

```js
  /* new format */
  var fmt = "0.00";
  /* change cell format of range B2:D4 */
  var range = { s: {r:1, c:convert_from_col}, e: {r:excel_row_list.length, c:excel_row_list[0].length} };
  for(var R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {
    for(var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
    // debugger;
      var cell = ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r:R,c:C})];
      if(!cell || cell.t != 's') continue; // only format numeric cells
      if(cell.v != "" && cell.v != "NA" && cell.v != "AB" && cell.v != "-"){
        cell.v = parseFloat(cell.v)
        cell.t = "n";
        cell.z = fmt;
      }
    }
  }

  /* generate workbook */
  var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "sheet1");

  /* generate file and download */
  const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { type: "array", bookType: "xlsx" });
  saveAs(new Blob([wbout], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), filename+".xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

should it be cell.t != 'n' ?

```
 if(!cell || cell.t != 's') continue; // only format numeric cells
```

anyway, still I couldn't find any solution for this question. fixing the entire column as number ,not 'general' doesn't seem to be doable.